# Bootstrap "container" background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been racking my brains for quite a bit of time but still was not find to find a variant but one I will describe here.
I’m using twitter bootstrap 2.3.2. I wanted to change the background of the "container". When I applied the changes, this image was also the background of "navbar" and "hero-unit".

The same thing you can discover here:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/hero.html
By setting in the "Inspect Element" of the "container" settings smth like this:

```
background-image: ('url');
```

It will not only set the image of the body, but also of the "navbar".

Surely, I clearly understand why, in my case, the background of "navbar" and "hero-unit" are changing, because I got this in the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="navbar">
  <div class="hero-unit">
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

But what I need, is that the "hero-unit" and the main content "container" were on one line (as on the link provided above). If they are applied to the "container" class it works, but the background is fairly. What properties do I have to apply to the new class, so as they are of equal size (see the link). I think I'm stuck a bit and badly need some support.

I guess I gotta create two new classes? One for the equal display of the "container" and "hero-unit" and "navbar" and the other (with same property of width) to set the background. But I cant figure it out:(

Comment: So you want a background on `container`, but not on `navbar` and `hero-unit`?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to stick to that markup?

Comment: Wait, that markup doesn't even make sense. Why would you put a hero unit inside of a navbar?

Comment: Could you not set the navbar above the container? I think Bootstrap have a fixed option that will do this? If this is not what you want, you could make a new div that wraps all the content where you want the image as background.

Comment: I wrote some sick stuff about my markup there. It really makes no sens. Probably the cause of almost ~9 hours of nonstop work on the markup. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy fix for your issue.

Use proper markup. It makes no sense to put a *hero-unit* inside of a *navbar* and after that put said *navbar* inside of your *container*.

```
<div class="navbar">
  <!-- Other stuff -->
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit"></div>
</div>
```

This is the markup you should use. **Then** you can create a separate class with your CSS properties and add that class to your DIV with the *container* class.